# Compilation errors in resolving public functions in C++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I'm trying a classic programming interview problem. The idea is to create a balanced binary tree(or a tree with minimum height) from a sorted array. This is my node class.

```
class node{

public:
    node(int data):value(data), left(nullptr), right(nullptr){}

    node* sortedArrayToBinaryTree(int arr[], int start, int end){

        if(start > end) return nullptr;

        int mid = (start + end)/2;

        node* p = new node(arr[mid]);
        p->left = sortedArrayToBinaryTree(arr, start, mid-1);
        p->right = sortedArrayToBinaryTree(arr, mid+1, end);
        return p;

    }

    void preorder(node* root){
        if(root == nullptr) return;
        std::cout<<root->value<<" "<<std::endl;
        preorder(root->left);
        preorder(root->right);
    }
private:
    int value;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};
```

I'm reasonably sure that my logic is ok. However the issue is when I write a client code to test the functionality my public methods in node class are not being resolved.

```
int main() {

    int arr[] = {2,7,9,13,19,21};

    node* root = sortedArrayToBinaryTree();
    preorder();

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following compilation error.

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'sortedArrayToBinaryTree'
    node* root = sortedArrayToBinaryTree(arr, 0, 5);
                 ^
main.cpp:10:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'preorder'
    preorder();
    ^
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: Downvote without a reason or even an answer is disgusting. Do you even know the answer.

Comment: Asking a unclear question without showing any research efforts is disgusting as well (wasn't me who downvoted, I'm actually out of downvotes today).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `sortedArrayToBinaryTree` is a non-static member function of class `node`.

It may not be called withput an object of this class.

You could declare it as a static data member in the class definition

```
static node* sortedArrayToBinaryTree(int arr[], int start, int end){
//...
```

and in this case you could write

```
node* root = node::sortedArrayToBinaryTree( /* arguments */ );
```

And as the function does not have default arguments you have to specify them explicitly.

The same is applied to funcion `preorder`.

Take into account that these functions do not use data members of the class. So the class design is wrong.

I think you should declare these functions as static member functions of the class.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot not only to pass actual arguments to the functions, but the fact, that these non-static member functions (methods) need a class instance to be called on. I don't see any.

Nevertheless, it doesn't make sense to make `sortedArrayToBinaryTree` and `preorder` members of `node`. If you're making a tree, there should be class `tree` that takes care of the sorting/ordering etc... So, logic is not OK.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting compiler errors since the functions `sortedArrayToBinaryTree` and `preorder` are declared in `node` as member functions and you are using them from `main` as though they are non-member functions.

I can think of the following ways you can resolve the problem.

**Make the functions non-member functions**

Declare the functions.

```
node* sortedArrayToBinaryTree(int arr[], int start, int end);
void preorder(node* root);
```

Make them `friend`s of `node`.

```
class node{

   public:
      node(int data):value(data), left(nullptr), right(nullptr){}

      friend node* sortedArrayToBinaryTree(int arr[], int start, int end);
      friend void preorder(node* root);

   private:
      int value;
      node* left;
      node* right;
};
```

And then use them from `main`, with right arguments.

```
int main() {

   int arr[] = {2,7,9,13,19,21};

   node* root = sortedArrayToBinaryTree(arr, 0, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));
   preorder(root);

   return 0;
}
```

**Make the functions `static` member functions**

```
class node{

   public:
      node(int data):value(data), left(nullptr), right(nullptr){}

      static node* sortedArrayToBinaryTree(int arr[], int start, int end);
      static void preorder(node* root);

   private:
      int value;
      node* left;
      node* right;
};
```

and call them from `main`.

```
int main() {

   int arr[] = {2,7,9,13,19,21};

   node* root = node::sortedArrayToBinaryTree(arr, 0, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));
   node::preorder(root);

   return 0;
}
```